# Expected behaviour of postcss css-next and custom-selector

Tags: css, postcss

In the following code I expected the title inside the wrapper to be blue but it stays red, I was hoping @custom-selector would act like regular css custom-property?

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
@use postcss-cssnext;
@custom-selector :--heading h1, h2, h3; 
 

:--heading{
  color: red;
}

a:active{
     color:hotpink;
}

.wrapper{
  :--heading{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised nesting was not suported so

```
.wrapper :--heading{
 color: blue;
```

works! Duh